# HTTP basic auth over SSL

Tags: http, .htaccess, ssl, https, basic-authentication

So, I have an SSL certificate for secure.domain.com. I run a few admin web applications on this domain (git repo etc), authenticated using .htaccess basic auth.

When I communicate with the domain over https and it asks me to authenticate, has it verified the certificate or does it verify after I've authenticated?

Similarly, if I connect over http, is there a simple way to forward to request to https and then authenticate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SSL or TLS session that HTTPS uses gets built before any HTTP traffic gets sent. This includes certification verification. Once the session is built, then HTTP traffic goes over it, starting with the GET/POST/whatever, then the server responds as normal, with the `WWW-Authenticate` header that triggers the login box.

As for redirecting to HTTPS from HTTP, that depends on what server you're using. Since it's tagged `.htaccess`, I'm going to assume Apache, for that, something like this in the `.htaccess` file should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Can I embed that in a File directive? I only want to forward for particular pages. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with rewrite rules in htaccess (I mainly use Cherokee under linux, or IIS under windows), but I don't see why not. Keep in mind, you'll have to be careful with any cookies with sensitive information from the HTTPS page. Something like this: http://www.mcgwebdevelopment.com/blog/redirect-only-specific-files-from-http-to-https/

Answer (score 2):

> When I communicate with the domain over https and it asks me to authenticate, has it verified the certificate or does it verify after I've authenticated?

SSL is a separate layer from the HTTP protocol, BASIC authentication is part of the HTTP protocol. The SSL handshake happens first before any protocol information is sent. Depending on the endpoints doing the handshake and how they go about verifying each other's certificate, it may not do any verification at all. But if it does happen (and probably all widely used browsers do), it happens during the handshake, before any authentication data is sent.

> Similarly, if I connect over http, is there a simple way to forward to request to https and then authenticate?

There's several ways to do this. There's a lot of questions on StackOverflow asking how to do this, search for "force https". It's probably going to come down to which config files you have access to. If you have access to your vhost config, then add a `Redirect` directive in the vhost for the *non-SSL* config and redirect to https. Otherwise you'll need to do this in an .htaccess file. Something along the lines of this (in your *non-SSL* site):

```
Redirect 301 / https://yourdomain.com/
```